# OptaPlanner: List as Planning Variable

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working on a project which includes OptaPlanner. [Here](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2016/10/26/DomainModelingGuide.html) I understand that a list cannot be annotated with `@PlanningVariable`:

> OptaPlanner currently doesn’t support a `@PlanningVariable` on a collection. Although a future version will support it for flexibility reasons, it probably has an inherent performance and complexity cost, so it might be better to avoid it anyway.

I was wondering if such a version supporting this feature is already available, even if I understand the problems it creates with performance and complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not yet available (and I can't speculate when it will be available), see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-728 for the specification.

It's an important issue.